# Forwarded or responded mails disappear from Lotus Notes inbox

Tags: lotus-notes

I have an issue with Lotus Notes email settings. I think somehow I changed a setting to hide or redirect all forwarded or replied to emails.

Anytime I forward or respond to an email it is no longer visible in the inbox. Now, when I search for the email from my inbox it will recover the said "email".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You may have toggled the show unread/show all button on the toolbar above the inbox listing. It's all the way on the right, so you may have to scroll over.